# main.ERROR: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Tags: session

Losing access to our admin panel and exception log is showing:

```
 main.CRITICAL: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /home/andy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php on line 132 {"report_id":"aeee1c0ff0afc07937a2ffe04c415f1c79a0c172c0074c8ae4b0d39e2e09d064","exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /home/andy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php on line 132 at /home/andy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
```

Anybody had similar or know a fix?

Comment: Was getting exact same issue but the admin panel was working in icognito mode.